# Update value in input field when changing using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two input types: "range" and "number". If I change the number using the input field, the value is updated in the header and at the range slide. 
However, I also would like to update the value in my input field, if I change it using the range slide. Right now, only the value in the header is updated.

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="amountController">
     <h2>{{"Amount: " + amount + "$"}}</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item range" id="index3-rangeAmount"> <i>5000$</i>
            <input type="range" name="volume" min="5000" max="50000" value="{{amount}}" ng-model="amount"> <i>50000$</i>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" id="index3-inputAmount" min="5000" max="50000" value="{{getAmount()}}" ng-model="amount">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function amountController ($scope) {
$scope.amount = 7500;
$scope.getAmount = function() {
    return $scope.amount;
};
```

}

Here is the link to the jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://%20jsfiddle.net/radogost/o47LLjk3/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mate,it's to do with the input type, as your input is number type, but the value you bind is text type, so you can use watch to fix this,  have create a fiddle for you, check this:

```
function MyCont($scope) {
$scope.value = 0;

$scope.$watch('value',function(val,old){
   $scope.value = parseInt(val); 
});
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2e15u0bm/

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't yet support `input type="range".

There is a [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/9715), which will handle `range` the same as `number`. It is marked to be fixed in version **1.5-Cadidate**. Anyway the issue is open already for quiet a long time. Hope the fix makes it into the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering a watcher like Kevin Simple suggested, you could register an on-change (ng-change) method for the input type range like

```
$scope.valueChanged = function() {
    $scope.amount = parseInt($scope.amount);
}
```

which will be called by `ng-change="valueChanged()"`:

```
<input type="range" ng-change="valueChanged()" name="volume" min="5000" max="50000" value="{{amount}}" ng-model="amount"> <i>50000$</i>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mL7aotr/)